# Can you give columns in Excel a variable name?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a fairly large Excel spreadsheet, there are around 4500 rows with 35 columns.

Our VBA code references columns by their letter (aka *A1*, *A2*, *A3* ... *A4500*) when modifying field values ... this is a limitation as we are unable to move columns around within our sheet without having to update all of our code to where that column has moved to.

Is it possible to give a column a variable name?

If column A currently holds `First Name`, is it possible to name this column `First_Name` so that regardless of where this column moves, it retains the `First_Name` reference?

Then in our VBA code we can say `First Name` instead of `A1`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to dimension (35) variables or Enums that correspond to the either columns or column numbers.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const Name As String = "A"
Public Const Age As String = "C"
Public Const ID As String = "F"
...
```

then when referring to the columns use the defined names ie. `Range(Name & 13).`

this way you only ever need to modify the `public const`ants when the order of column changes.

if you reference columns by numbers consider using Enum

```
Public Enum Col
    Name = 1
    ID = 2
    Age = 3
End Enum


Sub Main()
    Cells(1, Col.ID) = "ID HEADER"
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Nice one and congrats on 10k ;)

Comment: Good point. Do we need to do this at the top of each Sheet and Module? Or is it possible to do it globally in one location?

Comment: thanks @SiddharthRout ! join my party this weekend ;)

Comment: @Brad if you do that in your main module ( not Sheet and not ThisWorkbook but a standard Module1 ) and dimension it as `public const <varName> as <varType> = <value>` then it should be accessible throughout the VBA project meaning you can access the constants in all your modules

Comment: I can just combine all my modules into one correct? I had inherited this project and it has 4 right now for no real reason from what I can tell. Sorry, still new to VBA.

Comment: @Brad usually, it's better to split different parts of code into separate modules (1) for easier maintenance and (2) based on the logic of your subs/functions. Have a look at the [**MVC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern see if you get an idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that dynamically finds the column:

```
Sub test()
    Do While True ' Ctrl-Break to stop
        MsgBox ColByName(InputBox("Name:"))
    Loop
End Sub

Function ColByName(colName As String) As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    For iCol = 1 To UsedRange.Columns.Count ' need better upper range for code off of a sheet
        If Cells(1, iCol) = colName Then
            ColByName = iCol
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iCol
    ColByName = -1
End Function
```

I prefer the ENum route but sometimes it is just not practical and it can introduce maintenance issues.

An alternate approach is a collection indexed by name - rebuild the collection when the columns are moved etc. Note that the test shows the default compare is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

A technique I use frequently is to leverage an [Excel table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-an-excel-table-in-a-worksheet-HA010013764.aspx).  Using this command will create a special object within your worksheet that you can then reference within your VBA code.  (You can, of course, add a new Excel table programatically using VBA if you like.)

For example, if you have a data in your worksheet like:

```
+--------------+-------------+
|  First_Name  |  Last_Name  |
+--------------+-------------+
|  John        |  Smith      |
|  Sally       |  Jones      |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Once you convert it into an Excel table, you will be able to reference it using code like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SampleCode()
    '
    '  selects Last_Name column
    '
    Range("Table1[Last_Name]").Select


    '
    '  prints "Jones"
    '
    Debug.Print Cells(3, Range("Table1[Last_Name]").Column).Value
End Sub
```

Excel will create a sequential table name for your starting with `Table1`.  You can change this name within Excel or give it a unique name if you create it programmatically.