# Can you give columns a "variable name" for a specific sheet in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, so I have read this:

[Can you give columns in Excel a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644213/can-you-give-columns-in-excel-a-variable-name)

and from my understanding, I can essentially setting "Name" to equal A, such that when I do:

```
For i = 1 to 100

worksheets(Sheet1).Range(Name & i).Value = "poop"

next i
```

It will fill Cells A1:A100 with poop.

However, if I were to type:

```
worksheets(Sheet2).Range(Name & i).Value = "poop"
```

it would also fill A1:A100, except in Sheet 2 now.

Is there any way where "Name" is Sheet-specific?  Something like:

```
Sheet1.Name = "A"
Sheet1.Name = "F"
For i = 1 to 100

worksheets(Sheet1).Range(Name & i).Value = "poop"
worksheets(Sheet2).Range(Name & i).Value = "poop"
```

Would result in sheet1 having column A full of poop and sheet 2 have column F full of poop.  Maybe I'm being too picky because I know I can type "Sheet1.Name" and "Sheet2.Name" because they're of that object, but I'm trying to avoid that since I've already specified it in Worksheets() and it would make the code cleaner.

I was thinking I'd have to put it in to each sheet's module, maybe as a private because they are both called "Name", but I really don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create a new range object and then set that range object. A range can be a set of cells or a column or a row:

```
Dim rngCol as Range
Dim rngGroup as Range

Set rngCol = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
Set rngGroup = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F100")

rngCol.Value = "Poop"
rngGroup.Value = "Poop"
```

Or you can iterate through these after setting them:

```
For each rngCell in rngCol
     rngCell.Value = "Poop"
Next rngCell
```

Comment: For some reason, Worksheets(Sheet1) causes an Error 13, but explicitly naming each works.  Thanks!

Comment: yea... Sorry about that. I fixed it after you accepted the answer. You can do either Worksheets("Sheet1") or you can reference the actual worksheet (assuming the name is the same as the reference) with Sheet1.Range("...")

Answer (score 1):

## Code:

```
Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("A:A").Name = "PoopRange"
```

Then:

`Range("PoopRange")` will always refer to Sheet1, Column A.

You can use `Range("PoopRange").Cells(i,1)` to loop through each cell in that column.

Comment: It's saying Subscript out of range...  Is Name a valid object in Sheet 1?  I used it as an example, but I hadn't actually created it.
I'm sorry, I'm somewhat new to all this, VBS in Excel etc.

Comment: .Name is a valid property of a Worksheet object.  You can actually just call the worksheet object by using the (Name) property like: `Sheet1.Range(...)`  just look in the properties of the worksheet object in the editor for the (Name) parameter.